# Span width Related issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

in jsfiddle demo please give attention to position of "needed" word in ie9 it's coming on first line and in other browser it's going to second line i want this to go to second line in case of ie9 also.

[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/h7XuW/1/)

Comment: Have you tried these: Add a br? Set a width? Wrap another span around 'needed' and set to display: block?

Comment: i can't do any one of them according to client requirement just want "needed" to come on 2nd line in all browsers.

Comment: Surely `<br>` before the word would put it on the 2nd line. It’s a very clumsy workaround, but it would do the job. The cause of the problem looks obscure: it seems that in “standards mode”, IE 9 renders the text more compactly, making the word “needed” fit on the 1st line. (No, I am *not* recommending Quirks Mode though, as it would have unpredictable other effects.)

Comment: you could try experimenting with letter-spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference seems to be caused by the [new rendering features of IE 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you look at the page on IE 9 in different modes (use F12 and set document mode to Compatibility Mode vs. Standards Mode), you’ll see that the width of the text changes: letters are packed more tightly in Standards Mode. (It is not a letter spacing issue; rather, a matter of text rendering details such as sub-pixel rendering.)

If you just need to force a line break, use `<br>`. Otherwise, the approach depends on the goal. It is impossible to force browsers to render a piece of text exactly the same way, even though they obey you font family and font size settings.